# JavaScript Copy To Clipboard Jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clipboard

I have this function here, that is supposed to copy my discount code to the users clipboard. The discount code displays fine for the user, but when I try to copy it nothing appears to be copied to the clipboard.

```
}).done(function(data) {
 $('#discountCode').text(data.discount_code);
 var copyText = data.discount_code;
 copyText.select();
 document.execCommand("Copy");
})

};
```

I'm hoping it's a simple syntax error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. Include your HTML as well.

Comment: Why is this tagged with python?

Comment: Problem with Selecting text
Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse